# How to prove that the set of all exponential functions restricted to [0,1], T is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, exponential-function, solution-verification

Consider the vector space $C[0,1]$ and the following subset of $C[0,1]$: $$T = \{f_\lambda :[0,1]→\mathbb{R}\, | \, f_\lambda(x)=e^{\lambda x},λ∈\mathbb{R}\}$$

(that is, $T$ contains all the different exponential functions restricted to $[0, 1]$).

Note that, for every $λ_1,λ_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, if $λ_1\neq λ_2$, then $e^{λ_1} \neq e^{λ_2}$ ⇒ $f_{λ_1}(1) \neq f_{λ_2}(1) ⇒ f_{λ_1} \neq f_{λ_2}$. In other words, the cardinality of the set $T$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.
Prove that T is a linearly independent subset of $C[0,1]$.

Proof attempt:
Since the set T is clearly infinite, thus to show linear independence we need to prove every finite subset of T is linearly independent.

Therefore we take n elements {${e^{λ_1x_1},...,e^{λ_nx_n}}$} where $x \in [0,1]$
then we take scalars $a_1....a_n$ and set ${a_1e^{λ_1x_1}+...+a_ne^{λ_nx_n}}=0$

So here is where I get stuck/fuzzy, I believe this should be the end of the proof since there is no way the exponential function adds up to equal $0$ unless the scalars are equal to $0$ but I'm unsure.

corrections and critiques would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean exponential functions rather than exponential values? If functions, I think if you consider $\{e^{λ_1x},...,e^{λ_nx}\}$ with all $\lambda_i$ distinct you can prove that
this is linearly independent by induction.

It is true for $n=1$, clearly.

If $n=2$,
consider
$f(x)
=a_1e^{b_1x}+a_2e^{b_2x}
$.
If $f(x) = 0$ then,
dividing by
$e^{b_1x}$,
$0
=a_1+a_2e^{(b_2-b_1)x}
$,
and this can be true
only if $b_1 = b_2$.

The induction step for
$f(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke^{b_kx}
$
can be done
by noting that
if $f(x) = 0$
then
$0
=g(x)
=f(x)e^{-b_1x}
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke^{(b_k-b_1)x}
=a_1+\sum_{k=2}^n a_ke^{(b_k-b_1)x}
$
so that
$0
=g'(x) 
=\sum_{k=2}^n a_k(b_k-b_1)e^{(b_k-b_1)x}
$
but this can not be zero
by the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean $a_1e^{\lambda_1x} + \dots a_ne^{\lambda_nx} =0$ above. 
Why do you restrict to an interval btw?
For the linear independence you can extend to $ (0,\infty)$ wlog. Factor out the largest exponent (say it is $\lambda_n$) and we may assume that $a_n \neq 0$. Then notice that $e^{\lambda_nx}(a_n + \dots) =0$ but the expression in the bracket tends to $a_n$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$. This contradicts that $a_n =0$.

Answer (score 1):

You're stuck because you pick only one $x$.

Write $f_{\lambda}$ for the function $x \mapsto e_{\lambda x}$. You have to check that for every finite sequences $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_1, \dots a_n$, if the function $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_{\lambda_i} $ is **identicaly zero**, then all $a_i = 0$.

Now, you can start picking linear equations satisfied by the $a_i$s :
For $x = 0$ you get $\sum a_i = 0$.
For $x = 1$you get $\sum a_i e^{\lambda_i} = 0$.
For $x = \frac{1}{2}$you get $\sum a_i e^{\frac{\lambda_i}{2}} = 0$, etc.