# Linear independence of another set of infinite functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I think [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606952/how-to-prove-that-the-set-of-all-exponential-functions-restricted-to-0-1-t-is) comes closest to my problem but I tried the induction with the derivative and it seems the logic doesn't quite hold in my case.  I want to find out if the infinite set of functions of the form

$$x^q\ \sin^m{kx}\ \cos^n{kx}$$

for a known $k$ and nonnegative integers $q$, $m$, $n$, is linearly independent.  How to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this set of functions are linearly independent. For example,

$$\cos x -  \sin ^2 x\cos x - \cos^3 x = 0$$